# Apply select2 to elements in cloned node?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

All,

I have a PHP template file that generates a hidden div with 3 select fields.

```
<div>
    <div class="form-group accessory collapse">
        <select class="accessory" style="width:50%">
        </select>

        <span class="input-group-addon">×</span>

        <select class="accessoryQuantity" style="width:10%">
        </select>

        <select class="accessoryType">
        </select>
    </div>
```

Using jQuery to clone those nodes like so:

```
$newItem = $('.form-group.accessory.collapse').clone();
$newItem.removeClass('collapse');
```

I then tried to apply select2 to the cloned jQuery object like so but it just messes up the whole cloned node.

```
$newItem.select2();
```

How can I apply select2 to the cloned node?

Note: I tried applying select2 to the hidden selects but when you clone it, it messes up select2 dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same issue in the past and the best way I found to solve it was to destroy select2 on the original element before cloning it and then re-initialising select2 on the original and the clone.

e.g.

```
$original.select2('destroy');
var $clone = $original.clone();

// add the clone to the DOM, e.g.
$clone.insertAfter($original);

$original.select2({options});
$clone.select2({options});
```

The whole process is pretty fast, so I haven't had any issues with seeing the select2 destroyed and re-initialised on the original select.

Answer (score 1):

Try change

```
$newItem = $('.form-group. .accessory .collapse').clone();
```

to

```
$newItem = $('.form-group.accessory.collapse').clone();
```

Comment: Also, clone doesn't add the element to the DOM. You have to add it manually. You can try something like $newItem.appendTo( "body" ); before apply select2

Comment: Yea I know that, but how can I add select2 in memory and not on the DOM?

Comment: Why would you do that? It doesn't make any sense to use select2 to an element that doesn't exist on the DOM. An example of what you are trying to achieve would help